# class can be added on two divs on click with respect to their index

Tags: angular

I have multiple divs which are coming form backend, now I have an add a class 'collpased-card' or 'card' depending upon their active index

On click of particular div if it has 'collpased-card' class it will change to 'card' class and vice versa but the problem is at one time two div can have the same class

```
<li *ngFor="let cardDetails of levelCardDetails; let index = index">
   <div (click)="showCompeleteCard(index)" [ngClass]="(activeSkillCardIndex == index) ? 'card' : 
      'collapsed-card'">
   </div>
</li>

showCompeleteCard(index: number) {
    this.activeSkillCardIndex = index;
  }

  activeSkillCardIndex: number = 0;
```

Is there any way around for this?

Comment: I would add an optional property to the levelCardDetails array setted by default to false. Then you will trigger it change (from false to true and viceversa) and bind that option property to the ngClass.

Comment: didn't understood

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the collapse based on  a added property `isCollapsed`

Try this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfirwv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<li *ngFor="let cardDetails of levelCardDetails; let index = index">
   <div (click)="collapse(index)" [ngClass]="cardDetails.isCollapsed ? 'collapsed-card' : 
      'card'"> {{cardDetails.item}}
   </div>
</li>
```

.ts

```
 collapse(index) {
    if (!this.levelCardDetails[index].isCollapsed) {
      if(this.levelCardDetails.filter(item => item.isCollapsed == true).length < 2)
      this.levelCardDetails[index].isCollapsed = !this.levelCardDetails[index]
        .isCollapsed;
    } else {
      this.levelCardDetails[index].isCollapsed = !this.levelCardDetails[index]
        .isCollapsed;
    }
  }
```

Comment: No with this i can add class on every div
The requirement is maximum two div can have the class

Comment: Check the modified demo

Answer (score 0):

I would add an optional parameter that is needed to set the dynamic class.

Taking an example `levelCardDetails` as an array made by:

```
interface Something {
  index: number;
  name: string;
  active?: boolean = false;
}
```

We can then do an ngFor like you did:

```
<li *ngFor="let cardDetails of levelCardDetails; let index = index">
   <div (click)="showCompeleteCard(index)" [ngClass]="[cardDetails.active ? 'card' : 'collapsed-card']">
   </div>
</li>
```

And finally we can edit the function `showCompeleteCard`:

```
showCompeleteCard(index: number) {
    this.activeSkillCardIndex[index].active = !this.activeSkillCardIndex[index].active;
  }
```